# Elm : How to make use of value with (Result String Value)

Tags: elm

For example

```
fromIsoString : String -> Result String Date
```

`fromIsoString` will produce Ok (`Value`) ... Any methods that i can use to do something with the `Value`

As what i tested it is working with

```
text ( `Value` |> Date.add Days -1|> Date.toIsoString)
```

Method tried : `Date.fromIsoString "2018-09-26" |> Result.withDefault 0` gives error -> expects:

```
Result String #Date#
```

Ideally i want to transform ISO date (2020-05-10) into Date format and do something with the date like -1 day.

Reference : 
https://github.com/justinmimbs/date/blob/3.2.0/src/Date.elm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You’re seeing this `Result String #Date#` error because you’ve passed `Result.withDefault` a `number` where it expects a `Date`. If we look at the `withDefault` type annotation:

```
> Result.withDefault
<function> : a -> Result x a -> a
```

`withDefault` expects a default of the same type `a` as the successful result. Because you’ve specified `0 : number` as the default, its type becomes:

```
> \result -> Result.withDefault 0 result
<function> : Result x number -> number
```

Note that `result`'s type is `Result x number`, which doesn't line up with `fromIsoString`'s `Result String Date` output type.

**TLDR: Pass a `Date` as the default argument, e.g.:**

```
> defaultDate = Date.fromCalendarDate 2020 Jan 1
RD 737425 : Date
> Date.fromIsoString "2018-09-26" |> Result.withDefault defaultDate
RD 736963 : Date
```

Take a look at the [Elm `Result` documentation](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/core/latest/Result) for other functions you can call on values of type `Result String Date`